# svg getCTM() not getting the exact value

Tags: javascript, svg, svg-edit

I am working with the `svg-edit` for my project, and am altering the `svgedit.compiled.js` as per my need, here am getting some issues, want to get the selected elements `transform` which is in the `transform matrix` ,I can get the `transform` of the the selected element in svg.

My code to get the current `transform` if the element is follow

```
var my_selected= selectedElements[0].id;
//alert(my_selected);
var child_sel=$('#'+my_selected).children("g").attr('id');

var child_each=$('#'+my_selected);
    //console.log(child_each);
    child_each.each(function () {
        var child_trans = $(this).attr('transform');
        /* dx_x = x - start_x;
        dy_x = y - start_y; */
        $(this).children('g').each(function() {
        if(this.id!='drag_drop') {
        var test_x = $(this).attr('transform');
        console.log(test_x);
        var ss=this.getCTM();
        console.log(ss);
        }
        });
    });
```

But on the `console.log(test_x);` am getting the value as `matrix(0, 0.722035, -0.51, 0, 1561, 776.524)`
on the next line am getting the same elements `transform` by using `this.getCTM()` but it not getting the previous value instead of it am getting below values

```
rotation :  90
scaleX :    0.7220349907875061
scaleY :    0.5099999904632568
skewX :     90
skewY : 90
translateX :    4060
translateY :    2376.5234375
```

What am doing wrong here? any clue on this ?

Comment: Sorry i can't get you? @RobertLongson

Comment: What are the SVG elements i.e. the SVG file that you are calling this on.

Comment: file is `svgedit.compiled.js` svg element is `g`

Comment: That means nothing to most of us. Please attach the markup of that to the question.

Answer (score 0):

I am going off of memory here, but when the values were off by a very small amount, it was because of the border.  I believe it is because getCTM does not take the border width into consideration but the transform matrix does, or vice versa.   Try getScreenCTM or element.clientX if it exists.

Please create a fiddle demonstrating the problem for more help.